# Unable to compile JSX using web-pack with babel loader

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, jsx, babel-loader

I am trying to bundle a react app, using web-pack which uses babel loader to compile jsx files that fails for the syntax error.

```
  handleClick = () => {
    this.props.handleFixedClick();
  };

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (37:14)

  35 |   }
  36 |
> 37 |   handleClick = () => {
     |               ^
  38 |     this.props.handleFixedClick();
  39 |   };
  40 |
```

I tried changing the babel-loader version to 7.15 but to no effort. Following is my web-pack.config.js.

```
   test: /\.jsx?/,
   loader: 'babel-loader',
   exclude: /node_modules/,
   query:{
     presets: ['react','es2015']
   }
```

Following is my package.json

```
"@babel/core": "^7.5.5",
"babel-core": "^6.26.3",
"babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
```

Answer (score 1):

to use the class properties syntax ( e.g. lambdas inside a class) you also need 
the babel plugin  `@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties`

install it with 
`npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties`

Comment: Thanks for the direction but adding   "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.5.5" is giving the same syntax error still.

Comment: try adding a .babelrc file in the same directory as your package.json with `{
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"]
}` (see https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties)

Answer (score 0):

Try using babels transform-arrow-functions plugin. ([v7](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-arrow-functions) / [v6](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-arrow-functions))
Also decide on using version 6 of 7 of babel and go with it don't keep both of them as there are some breaking changes between them.